# Embed youtube video in iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, ios-simulator

I want to embed a youtube video into a webviewer whenever I press a button. I have this code

```
- (IBAction)testBtn:(id)sender {

    NSString *code = @"<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/1iBIcJFRLBA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

    [[self youtubeWebPlayer]loadHTMLString:code baseURL:nil];

}
```

My problem is, whenever I press the button nothing happens. The webviewer remains blank.

I have put breakpoints in the code to double check that the code is called by my app and it is indeed called.

EDIT*****

I have fixed the problem by replacing

```
    [[self youtubeWebPlayer]loadHTMLString:code baseURL:nil];
```

with

```
    [[self youtubeWebPlayer]loadHTMLString:code baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one this is working perfect.
You use youtube Url as "http://www.youtube.com/v/YOU_TUBE_VIDEO_ID".

```
 UIWebView * youTubeWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
    youTubeWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;
    youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
    youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay=YES;
    youTubeWebView.delegate=self;
    youTubeWebView.scrollView.bounces=NO;

    NSString *linkObj=@"http://www.youtube.com/v/1iBIcJFRLBA";//@"http://www.youtube.com/v/6MaSTM769Gk";
    NSLog(@"linkObj1_________________%@",linkObj);
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;color: white;}\\</style>\\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\\<embed webkit-playsinline id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \\width=\"320\" height=\"320\"></embed>\\</body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, linkObj];
    [youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:youTubeWebView];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately its still not working for me :/

Comment: Now you try this code i am sure its woking fine.
Please use youtube url which format i mention in top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code if you want to embed you tube video in swift

`let webViewYouTube = UIWebView()`

```
    webViewYouTube.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.width/2)

    webViewYouTube.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    webViewYouTube.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
    webViewYouTube.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true
    webViewYouTube.delegate = self as? UIWebViewDelegate
    webViewYouTube.scrollView.bounces = false
    webViewYouTube.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let linkObj = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swIoyaBUpEg"

    print("linkObj1_________________\(linkObj)")
    let embedHTML = "    <html><head>    <style type=\"text/css\">    body {    background-color: transparent;color: white;}\\</style>\\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\\<embed webkit-playsinline id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \\width=\"320\" height=\"320\"></embed>\\</body></html>"
    let html = String(format: embedHTML, linkObj)
    webViewYouTube.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    view.addSubview(webViewYouTube)
```