# autoplay on video in UIWebview,iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the URL for example `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2ccXwwmcnA`. If I pass this URL to `UIWebView` it automatically the `play` the Video. I  have the tried the following ways

**Option-1**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webvie; 


  NSString *url=@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jYa7dfrXKU";

  self.webvie.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
 self.webvie.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.webvie.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

[self.webvie loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

**Option-2**

```
NSString *youTubeHTMLTemplate = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body { background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>"; 
finalHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeHTMLTemplate, fullYopuTubeUrl, htmlFrameWidth, htmlFrameHeight];
```

**Option-3**

[How to autoplay a YouTube video in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/objective-c-how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview)

[I dont want auto play the in UIWebview play youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344439/i-dont-want-auto-play-the-in-uiwebview-play-youtube-video)

but all options does not helped me,

Comment: I think you have to add an `autoplay` attribute inside the `embed` tag.

Comment: Do you want to auto play the video or not auto play the video? Also, have you looked into using [YouTube`s Helper Library for iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)?

Comment: Already we tried with this, the link we attached the ID for play the video , but  my requirment is load the URL first after that I need the video want to play on automatically.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel -- Wait I try once

Comment: @ShangariC: just wondering how you're able to autoplay in UIWebView when Apple prohibits autoplay because it hogs user data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks @Kyle, I tried your comment , I added the `&autoplay=1` in after the URL it working perfectly. The answer is

```
NSString *url=@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jYa7dfrXKU&autoplay=1";


[self.webvie loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
self.webvie.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[self.webvie setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
```