# Embed iFrame in UIWebView in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, youtube-api, firebug

I want to play YouTube video in `UIWebView`, I followed so many links and I am able to embed videos in `UIWebView` but the problem is sometimes it will show the message **This video contains contents from Vevo**

But I found that whatever iFrame I am using it is working perfectly in browser using `firebug`.

**This is the iFrame which I using in browser**

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="320" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com /embed/w4s6eUZ2uGw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The same iFrame I am using in iOS device

```
<iframe id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"320\" height=\"300\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/w4s6eUZ2uGw?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>

[self.videoView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Please tell me if I am doing wrong anywhere.

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: Try This Link,I hope this will help full for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873203/embed-youtube-video-in-ios-app/18873523#18873523

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this later.  SME is Sony Music Entertainment.  This message means that a song or something in the video is infringing on Sony's copyrights.  Because of this they will not let the video be embedded.  If you have rights to play the video you can file a counter claim and prove that you legally can embed and share a video that contains Sony Music Entertainment content.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIWebView * youTubeWebView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
    youTubeWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;
    youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
    youTubeWebView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay=YES;
    youTubeWebView.delegate=self;
    youTubeWebView.scrollView.bounces=NO;

    NSString *linkObj=@"http://www.youtube.com/v/1iBIcJFRLBA";//@"http://www.youtube.com/v/6MaSTM769Gk";
    NSLog(@"linkObj1_________________%@",linkObj);
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;color: white;}\\</style>\\</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\\<embed webkit-playsinline id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \\width=\"320\" height=\"320\"></embed>\\</body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, linkObj];
    [youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:youTubeWebView];
```

Comment: Try this one this is working perfect. You use youtube Url as "http://www.youtube.com/v/YOU_TUBE_VIDEO_ID".